# Setting up Android Xamarin solution in Rider IDE doesn't detect framework

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, rider

Using a Mac with Rider IDE v2017.3.1 I'm attempting to create a new solution (project) which is a Xamarin application with a platform of Android. I'm getting an error message from framework stating *"no target frameworks were found on this machine"*

from what I've seen online it looks like I'm supposed to install a xamarin.android SDK (not android SDK provided by Google) but it appears this can only be added via Visual studios via the integrated SDK manager  [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin)

I have already installed Mono and .NET Core SDK.
Note if I click on any of the other platforms I don't get the above error message.

Comment: Do you see this message while opening any other example Xamarin solution? Perhaps check [requriements](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/208074835-Using-Project-Rider-on-Mac-prerequisites) - install either Mono or .NET Core SDK or upgrade to [Rider EAP 2018](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/eap/) (which I truly recommend).

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this I downloaded [visual studio for mac](https://www.xamarin.com/download). (you'll have to provide name and email). This downloaded visual studio community edition unfortunately its ~4GB. However once the download was complete and installed I quit Rider and started it back up again and the error message was gone. Maybe there is a way to get around this that doesn't require you to waste 4GB but knowing Microsoft "thats just the way it is".

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is experiencing this issue, the solution is, go to JetBrains Rider/Settings/Plugins Rider "Xamarin Android Support" and hit Upgrade, because this Plugin should be incompatible with your environment.